# Would Walder Frey have acted another way if Robb kept his promise?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S03E09,

> Walder Frey kills Robb Stark, his wife and his mother at the Red Wedding, under the supervision of the Lanisters.

He says it's because Robb Stark didn't keep his promise of marrying one of his daughter. But seeing how ruthless and cruel the character is, **wouldn't he have done what he did anyway?**

I would prefer to have a answer based on the show, but if only the books answer properly I will accept it.

Comment: nice one, also edmure tully is still alive.

Answer (score 9):

No he wouldn't.

He's an opportunistic weasel and he knew that the Starks were bound to be defeated. Lannisters had secured an alliance with Dorne and Reach, defeated the Baratheons. The prospects of a Stark victory looked even more bleak when Lord Glover's Army got destroyed in Duskendale.

The slight on his house's honor by Robb's betrayal sure played a role but he has suffered countless such slights before. So why was this one any different? Because he knew that Robb was doomed to be defeated and he did not plan to be on the losing side.

No House is inherently evil or inherently good. Nor is bravery hereditary. Freys fought bravely alongside Starks by accounts of Edmure. But why should they keep doing so? No reason at all.

Walder Frey did what he thought was best for house given the circumstances. Fight on, be defeated, be forced to pay hostages and reparations or possibly lose your head and lands in the bargain. Or you could switch sides and create a larger fortune for yourself and your house. Which one would you choose?

After all, Tullys got Paramount Lordship of Riverlands by betraying their liege lord King Harren the Black and switching side to Aegon the Conqueror when they saw that there was no victory against dragons. It's not the first time they did it either, Before Harren, Tullys betrayed King Teague as well by inviting Storm King to conquer Riverlands. Why is it wrong for Walder Frey to do exactly what Tullys themselves did 300 years ago?

Comment: I really like your answer, the only thing preventing me from accepting it is that it's purely based on character analysis rather than clear quotes from either the show or the book. I'll wait to see if there is any, if not I will validate this answer.

Comment: @sh5164 There is a quote "I doubt even lord Walder knows what Lord Walder will do". ;) Don't ever feel the pressure that you are expected to accept answers. If they don't satisfy you, they need not be accepted ever. If you want books answer with quotes, I'd suggest coming over to Scifi SE. I doubt books answer will be appreciated here and I just hang around here occasionally. Come over to SFF, there are many great folks there who can provide just the answer you are looking for (Yes, with quotes)

Comment: Actually I want show answers, it's just that if there is no show answer I'd rather have a book answer that none at all

Answer (score 1):

No, at least I don't think so.

They did it due to the influence of Lannister after teaming up of Bolton and Lannister to get Starks wiped out.

Frey House is not very well known for its honor or braveness, they are cowards and do things in the most hideous way possible.

The Red Wedding didn't happen because Frey was angry that Robb didn't marry his daughter. They had an agreement that someone will still Marry her daughter, it was Robb's Uncle. Even then they invited them to the wedding and killed them all brutally, why? Because Lannister and Bolton provided them support and influenced them to do so.

The only difference I think would be that Robb would have been kept as a hostage instead of being killed.